# How can I select which Java to use?

Tags: java, openjdk

I have installed both OpenJDK 6 and 7. When I run "java somefile" from the command line, OpenJDK 6 is invoked. I do not want to change this default behavior. What command can I use to run my non-default OpenJDK 7 installation instead?

(I am used to running "python somefile" to invoke the default Python, "python2.7 somefile" to use Python 2.7 specifically and "python3 somefile" to use Python 3 specifically.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could bind an alias to the specific java versions. Just add the following lines to your `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
alias java6='/path/to/java6/bin/java'
alias java7='/path/to/java7/bin/java'
```

Same for `javac` and you should be fine ;-)

Comment: the paths to the different java executables look like: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java

Comment: Java usually expects the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable to be set.    You should use something like `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

Answer (score 34):

You can select java version using `update-alternatives` command.

Run below command in terminal.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And type selection number that you want to use.

Like this:

[image: selecting java version]

**Caution:** 
The above description is the procedures for changing a default version. 
It is not an answer of this question, but it leaves for reference.

Comment: Much better to use update-java-alternatives instead. That way, you update all the java related commands.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a frontend to `update-alternatives` that updates all of the things related to Java:

```
$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64      1711       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64
```

```
java -version
$ java -version
openjdk version "17" 2021-09-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17+35-Ubuntu-121.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-Ubuntu-121.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
[sudo] password for user:
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: This is a good tip - using a different jre to jdk can cause problems